# FPDF - Adding a google webfont

Tags: php, fpdf

I'm using FPDF to generate a pdf with PHP and I want to use the same font than my website, Lato. But on my site, I use a google webfont link :

http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato%3A300%2C400%2C700%2C900%2C300italic%2C400italic%2C700italic

So I don't have the files and I want to know if there's a way to use this font in my pdf ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is download the font and install it in your system, and define the font path,

```
define('FPDF_FONTPATH','/home/www/font');
```

and then set the font accordingly - [doc link](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/setfont.htm)

```
// Times regular 12
$pdf->SetFont('Times');
// Arial bold 14
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',14);
// Removes bold
$pdf->SetFont('');
// Times bold, italic and underlined 14
$pdf->SetFont('Times','BIU');
```

FPDF accepts only `.ttf, .otf or .pfb` file type.

A quick googling will get you the [links](http://www.latofonts.com/download/Lato2OFL.zip) for Lato font,

Maybe you will have to check this link also ([Link](http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto7.htm))

Comment: Thanks, I knew there is this possibility, but if it's possible, I prefer to not download any font.
but if it's not, then I will use your solution, thanks ;)

Comment: @DarkCid you have to download the font

Comment: Can the font be downloaded on server and used?

Comment: Yes, you can download the font inside the server and give the path accordingly